# Bad Exit Status from rpmbuild on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm working on packaging up some work into an rpm.  I am doing this on Mac OSX after brew installing rpm.  I have a basic .spec file, but I am getting an error and have been unable to diagnose it:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba myapp.spec
Executing(%prep): %{__spec_prep_cmd} /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14478
error: Bad exit status from /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14478 (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14478 (%prep)
```

The spec files is as follows:

```
Name:           myapp
Version:        0.1.0
Release:        1
Summary:        Web service to do stuff
URL:            http://myapp.com
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/myapp-build-root

%description
My app

%prep

%build

%install

%pre

%preun

%postun

%clean

%files
%defattr(-,www-data,www-data,-)
%doc
```

This is my first time building an rpm, what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today. For no obvious reason the %prep macro fails, even without any content.

Running your spec on my Ubuntu box seems to work just fine after adding those two values:

```
License:        yourLicense
Group:          yourGroup
```

I have reason to believe, that rpm didn't get installed correctly on my box via homebrew. I think I aborted the process at some point, then forgot about it over lunch, but rpmbuild was available to use from within my script and I ran into the issue above.

I will try doing a clean install of the rpm formula in verbose mode to see whether my assumption is correct.

### Update:

I've installed rpm successfully, but it took an awful long time:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10: 187 files, 9.7M, built in 92.4 minutes
```

Nevertheless, it keeps on failing with the same error

```
rpmbuild -ba so.spec
Executing(%prep): %{__spec_prep_cmd} /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.69701
error: Bad exit status from /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.69701 (%prep)
```

With the content of /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.69701 saying:

```
%{__spec_prep_template}%{__spec_prep_post}
```